# Can we use reductions to design approximation algorithms for NP-hard problems?

Tags: reductions, np-hard, approximation, polynomial-time

Let us say that I have a problem $P(n)$ that I need to solve (where $n$ is the size of the input of problem $P$). I used a polynomial-time reduction from a known NP-hard problem $Q(m)$ (where $m$ is the size of the input of problem $Q$) to $P(n)$ and showed that $P(n)$ is NP-hard. The time complexity of the reduction is $O(n^k)$ for some fixed $k$.

Can I use a known approximation algorithm for problem $Q(m)$ that is $O(f(m))$-approximation for problem $Q(m)$ to design an approximation algorithm for problem $P(n)$ that is $O(g(n))$-approximation for problem $P(n)$?

Comment: Yes, if your reduction is approximation-preserving.

Comment: What are your thoughts?  Have you tried to prove that the answer is yes?  If so, where did you get stuck?

Comment: Thank you for your thanks.  For your information, comments are transitory and can be deleted at any time (e.g., when they've served their purpose, or if they are not aimed at improving the post or requesting clarification or providing additional information, roughly speaking).  See http://cs.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment: "Comments are temporary "Post-It" notes" and see "When should I comment?".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, but you need an [approximation-preserving reduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximation-preserving_reduction) in the opposite direction.